# Random Forest installation fails

Tags: r, random-forest

I tried installing randomForest package in R on a CentoOS 6 machine as follows:

```
install.packages("/var/installation_files/randomForest_4.6-12.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

However, it throws the following error:

```
> install.packages("/var/installation_files/randomForest_4.6-12.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package ‘randomForest’ ...
** package ‘randomForest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/vertica/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c classTree.c -o classTree.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/vertica/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c regTree.c -o regTree.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/vertica/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c regrf.c -o regrf.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/vertica/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c rf.c -o rf.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rfsub.f -o rfsub.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/vertica/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c rfutils.c -o rfutils.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/opt/vertica/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o randomForest.so classTree.o regTree.o regrf.o rf.o rfsub.o rfutils.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/opt/vertica/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [randomForest.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘randomForest’
* removing ‘/opt/vertica/R/library/randomForest’
* restoring previous ‘/opt/vertica/R/library/randomForest’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/var/installation_files/randomForest_4.6-12.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘/var/installation_files/randomForest_4.6-12.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**sessionInfo:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Can someone help with fixing this issue?

Comment: Please add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post.

Comment: Did you install the development version of R?

Comment: It is not a development version...It is the R version that comes with Vertica database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine after the devtoolset-2 we installed was enabled following the instructions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175851/how-to-permanently-enable-scl-centos-6-4

I was able to install the R package after this